# release managedObjectContext object c

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, dealloc

I have tried to use the Analyze instrument to see the memory leaks, and Xcode gives me a memory leak in this point:

.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

.m

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
```

then in the code I do this:

```
AppDelegate *appController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[self.managedObjectContext setUndoManager:nil];
[self.managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [appController persistentStoreCoordinator]];
```

and in the `dealloc` this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{    
    [__managedObjectContext release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

It gives me a memory leak on this line:

```
[self.managedObjectContext setUndoManager:nil];
```

for this object:

```
self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
```

I have released it in the `dealloc`, why a memory leak there?

Answer (score 2):

Your `_managedObjectContext` leaks because its retain count is increased twice, but you only release it once. You have made your property `strong` which means it will retain the object when it is assigned to it. But you also allocate `managedObjectContext` without autoreleasing (or manually releasing) it. Hence the error is in this line:

```
self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
```

The object you allocate will have a retain count of 1, but the synthesized property will retain it one more time, hence giving it a retain count of 2. When you release it in dealloc, it will stay around since it still has a retain count of 1.

What you need to do is *either* autorelease the object you allocate:

```
self.managedObjectContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or not call the synthesized setter, but assign directly to `_managedObjectContext`:

```
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
```

I would recommend the former since the latter will leak if `_managedObjectContext` is not nil. However if you're sure `_managedObjectContext` is nil before the assignment, you can pick either one you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so i have to do self.managedObjectContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] autorelease]; and in the dealloc i delete [__managedObjectContext release]; ?

Comment: @Piero Yes. The release has to be called in *dealloc* anyway. If you put *strong* (the same as *retain* in your code) you also need to release it when the object is destroyed. On the contrary, you have a memory leak.

Comment: ok so i have to edit only this: self.managedObjectContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] autorelease]; right?

Comment: if i do in this way, give me a bad_exc_access in the dealloc...on this line [__managedObjectContext release]; how i can do?

Comment: @Piero Are you sure you don't nullify the value before in your code? In other words, are you sure that you don't call `self. managedObjectContext = nil`? Try also to enable zombies and see what it happens (search enable zombies in Xcode).

Answer (score 1):

This line...

```
self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
```

...increases the retain count by two, one for the alloc and one for the "strong" on the property.

Try:

```
__managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
```

Comment: ok, but i don't have the arc, i can use retain nonatomic instead of strong?...and then i have still to do this?  self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init]; or i can delete that line?

Comment: I suggest changing the one line, as suggested, and then you will see whether or not your leak goes away.